# Circular motion speed of object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

When I apply the formula for it $v^2/r=(mg+m)/m$ I found the result $\sqrt{220}$. But the answer is $20\ {\rm m/s}$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the formulas correctly but did a silly mistake.

> The main point to note is that **the force exerted by the track at X is equal to it's weight ($mg$) and not it's mass**.